# Абсолютно упругое столкновение круглых частиц

Tags: android, java, физика

Мне нужно рассчитать проекции скоростей круглых тел после их упругого столкновения. Класс частиц выглядит примерно так:

```
class Particle{
  double m,r //масса и радиус
  x,y,//координаты
  vx,vy;//проекции скоростей
  ...
  Прочие переменные и методы
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, проблема в проектировании программной архитектуры или в описании физической модели?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, значит, неправильно считаете. При абсолютно неупругом столкновении двух объектов они слипаются в один, и их конечные скорости становятся одинаковыми. Какие проблемы могут возникнуть с решением уравнения `m1 * v1 + m2 * v2 = (m1 + m2) * v` в векторном виде - я не представляю.

Comment: @foti1ton, извиняюсь, моя ошибка. В вопросе хотел спросить про абсолютно упругое столкновение.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, а для абсолютно упругого столкновения нужно составить систему из двух уравнений - по количеству неизвестных. В вашем случае нужно составить уравнения по на законам сохранения импульса и сохранения энергии.

    m1 * v1 + m2 * v2 = m1 * v1' + m2 * v2'
    m1 * v1^2 + m2 * v2^2 = m1 * v1'^2 + m2 * v2'^2

Решите эту систему - и получите выражения для скоростей частиц после столкновения.

Comment: @fori1ton, решая эту систему, я получил квадратное уравнение, решив которое, мы получим два варианта решения. И какой выбирать?

Comment: @fori1ton, стоп. В первом уравнении скорости в векторах, а во втором только значения. Как решить эту систему?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, в первом уравнении используются непосредственно векторы, во втором - их модули. Задача определения скоростей тел после упругого столкновения очень распространённая и решена множество раз до вас. Возьмите формулы из соответствующей [статьи][1] из Википедии.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это так (при условии, что шары движутся строго равномерно-прямолинейно):

[image]

1. Переходим в систему координат, где шар `m1` стоит, а второй `m2` на него налетает.
2. В такой системе у налетающего шара всего два параметра - скорость движения и прицельный параметр `d` - по сути, расстояние между центрами шаров по оси столкновения.
3. Сталкиваем шары и в момент столкновения раскладываем скорости на две составляющие - нормальные (вдоль `r1` и `r2`) и тангенциальные перпендикулярно к ним. Понятно, что расклад на тангенциальные и нормальные составляющие будет зависеть от прицельного параметра и радиуса шаров.
4. Теперь следим за ручками: после удара меняются только нормальные составляющие ударов, а тангенциальные остаются прежними (в предположении абсолютно упругого удара, конечно).
5. Нормальная составляющая скоростей до и после удара находится просто - через закон сохранения энергии и импульса.
6. После небольших вычислений находим все компоненты скорости и осуществляем обратный переход в начальную систему координат.

В общем, как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Не буду минусовать, но, у вас ни формулы нет, ни наработок, ни вопроса сформулированного точнее. Ваш вопрос предполагает от пользователей изучить тему, про эти самые частицы, найти формулы и т.д., написать программу и скинуть весь код для копирования, так сказать, под ключ? А в какой среде разрабатываете?
Демонов выпустил, теперь по делу.
Нужно на бумаге все рассчитать. Далее подумать, как можно это реализовать на языке программирования, попробовать самому это проделать, и потом спросить, и выложить наработки, и задать вопрос, ЧТО не получилось. И тогда вам смогут дать ответ.

Comment: @Garf1eld, я пытался рассчитать это на бумаге по закону сохранения импульса, но там, чтобы найти конечную какой-либо частицы, необходимо знать конечную скорость другой частицы. В этом-то собственно и проблема.